# Finding average of random numbers from 1 to 50 in c++

Tags: c++, c++14

I need to find 50 random numbers (from 1 to 10) and then find the average, i know how to find randoms but i am having trouble with average, this is what i have so far..

```
srand(time(0));
for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
    cout << 1 +(rand()%10) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the sum of all them?

Comment: Figure out how to find the average of non-random numbers, and apply the same algorithm to the random numbers.

Comment: @churill Accumulating the numbers should be enough, no need to store all of them.

Comment: Please *don't* use `rand`. We have [much better tools](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) these days. See also [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: @churill not sure if this is what you mean, but a running average has worse numerical stability, in presence of no rounding errors you would get the same result. Thats not exactly the same as being an approximation

Comment: Please do the maths first. Writing code without knowing what it should do is possible but unnecessarily difficult. Do you know how to calcuate an average with pen and paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a variable `sum` and keep adding generated random numbers to it, then at the end divide it by 50:

```cpp
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
    int number = 1 + (rand() % 10);
    cout << number << endl;
    sum += number;
}
double avg = sum / 50.0;
cout << avg << endl;
```

Comment: Normal loops would be 0 to less than N.

Answer (score 4):

First lets define the formula for calculating the average. Add up all the random numbers that you generate and then divide by the number of generated numbers, 50 in your case. Let's use `n` as the number of random numbers to generate:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const int n = 50;
  int sum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      int number = 1 + (rand() % 10);
      std::cout << number << std::endl;
      sum += number;
  }

  double avg = static_cast<double>(sum) / n;
  std::cout << avg << std::endl;
}
```

Now to address the random number generation. There are better ways to generate random numbers than using `rand()`. Here is a simple way to generate random numbers between `low` and `high` inclusively:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  // random number generator
  const int low = 1;
  const int high = 10;
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 mt(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(low, high);

  const int n = 50;
  int sum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      int number = dist(mt);
      std::cout << number << std::endl;
      sum += number;
  }

  double avg = static_cast<double>(sum) / n;
  std::cout << avg << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Right, I flip flopped between making `sum` a double and `static_cast`ing. Which would you say is better?

Comment: I think I prefer the cast in the final calculation. It's simpler than doing a bunch of floating point addition in a loop. I might change my mind if an `int` was too small to hold the sum.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using modern C++ features for generating random numbers. First, [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) is used only once to seed the random number generator which is, in the below case, [`std::mersenne_twister_engine`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine). It is a random number engine based on Mersenne Twister algorithm and it produces unsigned integer numbers. Then, [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) uses the previously mentioned generator to produce random integer values uniformly distributed on the closed interval **[1, 10]**.

Full code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(1, 10);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        sum += distr(eng);
    }

    double avg = sum / 50.0;
    std::cout << avg << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Crandom%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::random_device+rd%3B%0A++++std::mt19937+eng(rd())%3B%0A++++std::uniform_int_distribution%3C%3E+distr(1,+10)%3B%0A%0A++++int+sum+%3D+0%3B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+50%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A++++++++sum+%2B%3D+distr(eng)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++double+avg+%3D+sum+/+50.0%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+avg+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.637075718015666,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'--std%3Dc%2B%2B14',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:37.5,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.362924281984334,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)